# How to get list of traits that were mixed in the specified class?

Tags: scala, traits

And more specific example:

```
abstract trait A
trait B extends A
trait C extends A
```

How to check what traits that extend trait A (it can be from 0 to many) were mixed in specified class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a hybrid of the other answers

```
abstract trait A //interested in this one
trait B extends A //and this one
trait C extends A //this one too
trait D //don't care about this one though

val x = new A with B with D
x.getClass.getInterfaces.filter(classOf[A].isAssignableFrom(_))
```

returns

```
Array[java.lang.Class[_]] = Array(interface A, interface B)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val x = new A with B with C
x: java.lang.Object with A with B with C = $anon$1@8ea25fa

scala> x.getClass.getInterfaces
res11: Array[java.lang.Class[_]] = Array(interface A, interface B, interface C)
```

Comment: I had thought about this obvious method but decided to ask here because traits as I know can compile in sophisticated ways.

Comment: Never resort to using reflection when the language features suffice.

Comment: Agreed.  I first used isInstanceOf - which replied to the body of his question.  But I switched to getInterfaces when I re-read his actual question title "How to get list of traits...".

Comment: Ah. The reading comprehension aspect... There will, in the not-too-distant-future, be a Scala-specific reflection interface, but I believe it is currently nascent. (Sorry, but I can no longer undo my down-votes on the reflection-based ansers.)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
def getTraitsExtending(clazz:Class[_], baseTrait:Class[_]): Seq[Class[_]] = {
  clazz.getInterfaces().filter { baseTrait isAssignableFrom _ }
}
```

This finds all traits that `clazz` implements that are themselves subtraits of `baseTrait`. With the following traits:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
trait C extends A
trait D
```

Use as follows:

```
scala> val x1 = new C with B
x1: java.lang.Object with C with B = $anon$1@51d92803

scala> getTraitsExtending(x1.getClass, classOf[A])
res0: Seq[Class[_]] = WrappedArray(interface C, interface B)

scala> val x2 = new C with A            
x2: java.lang.Object with C with A = $anon$1@f8db08

scala> getTraitsExtending(x2.getClass, classOf[A])
res1: Seq[Class[_]] = WrappedArray(interface C, interface A)

scala> val x3 = new C with D             
x3: java.lang.Object with C with D = $anon$1@2bbd83d

scala> getTraitsExtending(x3.getClass, classOf[A])
res3: Seq[Class[_]] = WrappedArray(interface C)
```

This only looks at the interfaces that are the directly implemented by the class of the instance passed in, but could be extended to recursively look up the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like my answer + a bit of boilerplate :)

Comment: @Kevin - the date stamps say that your answer looks an awful lot like my answer... :-P

Comment: That's not what I see when I order by "newest" :)