# Given an instance of any class type, how to find out which parent class and/or traits it inherits from or implements?

Tags: scala

Suppose there are class/trait definitions as follows:

```
trait T1 {}
trait T2 {}
abstract class A{}

class B {}
class C extends A with T1 with T2 {}

val b = new B with T1
val c = new C
```

Given the instance of b and c, how do I get their inheritance information (i.e. to know that b implements T1, and c implements A, T1 and T2) ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809463/how-to-get-list-of-traits-that-were-mixed-in-the-specified-class/2811089

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't know the type of the object (you have some `AnyRef`) and just want to test whether it's instance of some class or trait, then you can use `isInstanceOf`:

```
b.isInstanceOf[T2]
```

If you then want to cast it to that type, then use `asInstanceOf`

```
b.asInstanceOf[T1]
```

---

From the other hand, if you don't know what you are searching for, then you can try to use Java reflection. To get list of implemented traits and interfaces use:

```
c.getClass.getInterfaces
```

To get superclass use:

```
c.getClass.getSuperclass
```